# Visual studio 2012 don't work with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I wrote a simple program by visual studio 2012 using OpenGL. Building has no error. But when I press F5 to Debug, a console window appear but nothing else. And Debug is still running. Just like is take a long time to finish. Specially, when I press `ALT+F2` to Debug+Analysis, two windows appear: one is console window, another is a red square which I write.

So, I don't know if the problem is from Visual Studio software or from the OpenGL lib. Visual Studio worked well in the past.

This is the code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void mydisplay() { 
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
   glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
   glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5); 
   glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5); 
   glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5); 
   glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5); 
   glEnd(); 
   glFlush(); 
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
   glutCreateWindow("simple"); 
   glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay); 
   glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you installed `glut32.dll` on your machine?

Comment: Why aren't you calling `glutInit()`?  It's *not* optional.

Comment: @barak: if he didn't have the DLL the executable wouldn't launch at all.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`glutInit()`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node9.html) before `glutCreateWindow()`.